# What should the action attribute in menu.xml be?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, magento-2.1, menu

In the file `menu.xml` located in `MyNamespace\Mymodule\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml`, I understand that this file allows me to add new items to the navigation menu in admin panel.

In the `<add>` tags, there is an `action` attribute that contains values that look like `something/somethingelse`. For eg:

```
<add id="MyNamespace_MyModule::mymodule_testing" title="Some title" module="MyNamespace_MyModule" sortOrder="10" action="Part_A/Part_B" />
```

What should be entered in the `Part_A` and `Part_B` of the `action` attribute? I doubt they are arbitrary. What do they refer to and what do they stand for? What effects would it have if I put in a wrong thing into this attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have the following:

In your `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml` you declare the following route name:

```
<route id="hello" frontName="hello">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" />
</route>
```

Then under `Controller/Adminhtml` you have a folder called `World`

And finally in this `World` folder you have an action class called `Grid.php`

Then the `action` attribute to access this controller action class should be `hello/world/grid`

Comment: Ahh, this time Marius beats by few seconds :)

Answer (score 5):

the action part of the menu is the actual url of the menu item.
It should be `module/controller/action` or `module/controller` if the action is `index`.
take a look at [this example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml#L10) from the core for the cms page menu link

```
<add id="Magento_Cms::cms_page" title="Pages" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="0" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/page" resource="Magento_Cms::page"/>
```

`action` looks like this:  `action="cms/page"`.
This means that the menu item is going to link to the `cms` module and the `Page` controller and `index` action.

the first part `cms` in this case, is the front name you declared in the `adminhtml/routes.xml` [for your menu](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml#L10).
The second part is the name of the controller folder (lowercase) found int the `Controller` folder and the last part is the actual controller action file (lowercase and without the php extension) or it can be missing if the action name is `index`.

Comment: The first part is not necessarily `module` it could be anything defined in the `routes.xml`

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like it is the module name all the time

Comment: it usually is, but I changed that to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

The action attribute is the **action** which you want to do **after** **clicking** on that **menu**.you need to pass url over there **front name/yourcontroller/action**.

Lets take example of magento-catalog module.

```
<add id="Magento_Catalog::catalog_products" title="Catalog" translate="title" module="Magento_Catalog" sortOrder="10" parent="Magento_Catalog::inventory" action="catalog/product/" resource="Magento_Catalog::products"/>
```

Here action is catalog/product so **catalog** is the **controller** and **product** is the action and it will go tho that particular url and perform the action.